# How to display json object parameters in angular 2 template typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display Object in template . In console **Users.email** is working but in template its not working. Is it mandatory to define type of Users object. how to handle response properly.In console data is shown as object of users from which I am taking first object as data[0].

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }  from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from './services/authentication.service';
import { EmployeeService }       from './services/emplyee.service';

@Component({
    template: `<h2>Welcome, {{ Users.email }}</h2>
    <button class="btn btn-info bg-blue bg-darken-2 mt-1 min-width-150" (click)="logout()"><i class="icon-unlock2"></i>
        Logout
    </button>`,
})
export class homeComponent implements OnInit {

    Users: any;

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                private router: Router, private
                emplyeeService: EmployeeService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            console.log("Go Login");
        } else {
            this.getUsers();
        }
    }

    logout() {

        this.authenticationService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }

    getUsers() {
        this.emplyeeService.getAll()
            .subscribe(
                (data: any) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.Users = data[0];
                    console.log(this.Users.email);
                },
                (error) => console.log(error)
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: A side note. It is convention in TypeScript (and JavaScript) to use camelCase for local variables and field names. And to use PascalCase for classes and types. So Users -> users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using Observables so the data will be little delay in time so you need to type safe opertaor **`?`** as below

```
<h2>Welcome, {{ Users?.email }}</h2>
```

Comment: Is there any other solution? Like do I have to define type of user object?

Comment: yes exactly. you have to define a model. and then use it in your component