# How To Pass Data To Another Component Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that loads a data object that I use for display and to pass back to svc, but I also need to show another component using a selector when a user clicks and "Edit Address" link. I can display the component content with a static text in a div, but when I try to access the data from the parent component I get cannot find property of undefined.

The below function is where I expose the properties from the parent component:

```
openAddress(){
  this.openChangeAddress = true;
  this.shippingAddress = this.qrData.ShippingAddress;
  this.billingAddress= this.qrData.BillingAddress;
}
```

This is my child component where I'm trying to access those properties.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';

@Component({
selector: 'change-address',
templateUrl: './changeAddress.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./changeAddress.component.css']
})

    export class changeAddress {
    constructor() {}
    @Input('shippingAddress') ShippingAddress:{};
    }
```

And here's my child template, I'm sure it's something simple, just still learning Angular 2.

```
{{ShippingAddress.Street1}} //This says cannot read Street1 of undefined
<div class="col-3">Is This Showing Up?</div> //This displays onClick
```

Here is my added Parent Template

```
<div class="jumbotron qr-container">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="qr-inner">
  <form [formGroup]="complexForm" (ngSubmit)="findScript(complexForm.value)">
      <h2>Script Number</h2>
      <input type="number" name="script" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="scriptno" (blur)="getScripts(scriptno)" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['scriptnumber']">
      <h2>Date of birth</h2>
      <input type="date" name="dob" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dateofbirth" (blur)="getScripts(scriptno, dateofbirth)" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['dateofbirth']" required>
      <div *ngIf="showDeliveryTypes" name="deliverytypes">
      <h3>Delivery Method</h3>
      <select #select [(ngModel)]="selectedId" (change)="validateDeliveryTypes(select.value)" name="deliveryoptions" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['deliverytype']">
    <option *ngFor="let item of qrData.DeliveryTypes" [value]="item.DeliveryTypeId">{{item.DeliveryTypeName}}</option>

      </select>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="showPickupLocations" name="pickuptypes">
      <h3>Delivery Method</h3>
      <select #select [(ngModel)]="selectedPickupId" (change)="checkVals(select.value)" name="pickupoptions" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['pickuplocation']">
    <option *ngFor="let item of selectedItem.PickupLocations" [value]="item.PickupLocationId">{{item.PickupLocationName}}</option>

      </select>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="showPaymentOptions" name="paymentoptions">
      <h3>Payment Types</h3>
      <select #select [(ngModel)]="selectedPayment" (change)="checkVals(select.value)" name="selectpaymentoptions" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['paymentoptions']">
        <option *ngFor="let item of selectedItem.PaymentTypes" [value]="item.PaymentTypeId">{{item.PaymentTypeName}}</option>

      </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submitbutton" [disabled]="!complexForm.valid">Find Prescription</button>
  </form>
  <div *ngIf="userMessage">
    <h1>{{userMessage.heading}}</h1>
    <h4>{{userMessage.statusMsg}}</h4>
    <div class="address">
      <p>
        {{qrData.ShippingAddress.Street1}}<br>
        {{qrData.ShippingAddress.Street2}}<br>
        {{qrData.ShippingAddress.State}}<br>
        {{qrData.ShippingAddress.Zip}}
      </p>
      <div (click)="openAddress()">[edit address]</div>
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="userMessage.canDoSubmit">Submit Prescription</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<change-address *ngIf="openChangeAddress"></change-address> // this loads the child template from above
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show where you are calling the child component in the html ?

Comment: You are probably not passing the data in your html correctly. Please provide your html template of the parent component (not the `changeAddress` component!)

Comment: I have included my parent html template. I load the child selector at the bottom when openChangeAddress == true.

Comment: have a look at this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221959/how-to-display-json-object-parameters-in-angular-2-template-typescript/43222071#43222071) and comments too

Comment: @billy_comic did you check that answer

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't the issue I was having as the data had already be retrieved and stored in a variable. I had to add [shippingAddress]="ShippingAddress" to my <change-address> to bind that data object to the child component.