# Dynamically changing of image based from if statement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to display on my html what should be the image based from my if statement.

On my Typescript:

```
styleArray = ["Solitary", "Visual","Auditory","Logical","Physical","Social","Verbal",];
    constructor(){
     for (var i = 0; this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length - 1; i++) {
    if (this.arrayTest[0].style == this.styleArray[i]) {

      this.styles = [
        {
          src: './assets/img/' + this.arrayTest[0].style + '.png',
          /* button: this.styleArray[i] + 'InstructionPage', */
          button: 2
        }
      ];
      console.log("First: " + this.styleArray[i]);
    }
  }


   for(var i=0;  this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length -1 ; i++){
   if (this.arrayTest[1].style == this.styleArray[i]){
     this.styles = [
       { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
         button:3
       }
     ];
     console.log("Second: " +this.styleArray[i]);

   }
  }

  for(var i=0;  this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length -1 ; i++){
   if (this.arrayTest[2].style == this.styleArray[i]){
     this.styles = [
       { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
       button:4
       }
     ];
     console.log("Third: " +this.styleArray[i]);

   }
  }
  for(var i=0;  this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length -1 ; i++){
   if (this.arrayTest[3].style == this.styleArray[i]){
     this.styles = [
       { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
       button:5
       }
     ];
     console.log("Fourth: " +this.styleArray[i]);

   }
  }
  for(var i=0;   this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length -1 ; i++){
   if (this.arrayTest[4].style == this.styleArray[i]){
     this.styles = [
       { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
       button:6
       }
     ];
     console.log("Fifth: " +this.styleArray[i]);

   }
  }
  for(var i=0;  this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length -1 ; i++){
   if (this.arrayTest[5].style == this.styleArray[i]){
     this.styles = [
       { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
       button:7
       }
     ];
     console.log("Sixth: " +this.styleArray[i]);

   }
  }
  for(var i=0;  this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length -1 ; i++){
   if (this.arrayTest[6].style == this.styleArray[i]){
     this.styles = [
       { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
       button:8
       }
     ];
     console.log("Seventh: " +this.styleArray[i]);

   }
  }
    }
```

On my HTML:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[0].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[0].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[1].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[1].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

   <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[1].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[1].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[2].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[2].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[3].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[3].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[4].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[4].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[5].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[5].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-25>
      <ion-card class="card-5 full">
        <img class="list" [src]="styles[6].src" (click)="commonMethod(styles[6].button)" />
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

For example:
I got is the sorted styles from top 1 to top 7 , it should display the image and its button on my view in order displaying from the highest down to the lowest on my HTML.

I'm having an error which is "src" & "button" undefined. - What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points need to change here,

1. remove **,** at last in styleArray
2. Declare styles outside of Constructor.
3. use Angular image [src] property to display image.

**Code**

```
 styleArray = ["Solitary", "Visual","Auditory","Logical","Physical","Social","Verbal"];
    styles = [{ src: './assets/img/defaultAvatar.png',
                  button: 'someMethod1'},
              ];
    constructor(){
        for(var i=0; this.styleArray && i <= this.styleArray.length -1 ; i++){
            if (this.arrayTest[0].style == this.styleArray[i]){
              this.styles = [
                { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
                  button: 'AuditoryInstructionPage'},
              ];
             console.log("First: " + this.styleArray[i]);
            }
       }
    }
commonMethod(methodName){
    // If function name comes with () then remove by string manipulation
    //This code will call your method by string 
    this[methodName](); // Pass params if required
}
```

> HTML

```
<ion-row *ngFor = "styleElement in styles">
   <ion-col width-25 >
            <ion-card *ngIf = "styleElement && styleElement.src && styleElement.button" class="card-5 full">
      <img class="list" [src]="styleElement.src" (click)="commonMethod(styleElement.button)" />
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Raja Mohamed, I have tried your solution and it works! But I have question for this part: 

 { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
 button: 2},

 commonMethod(type){
  if (type && type == 1){
    
  } else if (type && type == 2){
    this.SocialInstructionPage();
  }
}

What if theres a different button? like

AuditoryInstructionPage(); 

how am i supposed to do that

Comment: @AngularNewbie i have edited the answer as per your requirement. You can pass method name as string and call on click from commonMethod by passing parameters . I hope it will help to meet your requirement.

Comment: Since you have method name in string format you cant call directly from html. So you can use this bypassed way.

Comment: Lets say I have 7 Images. I want to display it sorted out. How can I display it on my HTML? I think something is wrong with my for loop

Comment: 1. first remove wrong comma symbol at end of the array styleArray = ["Solitary", "Visual","Auditory","Logical","Physical","Social","Verbal",];

Comment: 2. you should declare styles = [{ src: './assets/img/defaultAvatar.png',
                  button: 'someMethod1'},
              ]; because your page is getting ready before the styles array getting prepared. Declare with dummy Array element out side of constructor

Comment: Follow the procedures what given in my Answer

Comment: one doubt from where this.arrayTest is coming ?? Have you declared and populated values init??

Comment: arraytest's values comes from the firebase. this.learningStyleObject.subscribe(snapshots => {     snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {       this.arrayTest.push(snapshot.val());});this.arrayTest.sort(function (a, b) {
return parseInt(b.value) - parseInt(a.value);});

Comment: Its Working! All I have to do is display the Images in order. I think somethings really wrong with my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are having `styles` as array

```
this.styles = [
            { src: './assets/img/'+ this.styleArray[i] + '.png',
              button: this.styleArray[i] + 'InstructionPage()'},
          ];
```

And you are trying to access its properties, so use them as below,

```
<img class="list" src="{{this.styles[0].src}}" (click)="{{this.styles[0].button}}" />
```

Update 1 :

```
//Declare variable
styles:any[] = [];
```

Use `ngIf` to prevent this error

```
<ion-row *ngIf="styles.length > 0">
       <ion-col width-25 >
                <ion-card class="card-5 full">
          <img class="list" src="{{this.styles[0].src}}" (click)="{{this.styles.button}}" />
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Why am I having an error in interpolation and it cannot read property '0' of undefined?

Comment: OnInit of your component `HTML` will be rendered so it breaks the application. Use type-safe operator **`?`** as per this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221959/how-to-display-json-object-parameters-in-angular-2-template-typescript/43222071#43222071)

Comment: Like this: 

<img class="list" src={{this.styles[0]?.src}} (click)={{this.styles[0]?.button}} />

Comment: still having problems with interpolation and cannot read property 0 of undefined

Comment: @AngularNewbie when declaring the variable initialize it `styles:any[ ] = [ ] `

Comment: Thanks mate! I added this.styles[0].src on it. but on my button interpolation keeps on showing up

Comment: for the "src", yes it is working but for my (click). I'm having an interpolation error.

Comment: @AngularNewbie cause you should be using a method inside a `click` event whereas you are declaring some statement.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I do it if there's a multiple image?

Comment: are you trying for a slider?